# Python Turtle - How to determine shortest turn direction

Tags: python, python-turtle

I have a turtle object, t, that I want to turn toward the center point. I've used t.heading() to get the turtle's current heading and t.towards(0, 0) to get the desired heading. How can I determine whether a right or left turn is shorter?

Ultimately, I want to rotate the turtle in the direction of the center point but not actually point it directly at the center. So I need to know which direction will turn it closer to the center heading.

Comment: Draw a diagram to make it easier to understand. You know the direction you're pointing (`current`). You know the direction you want to point (`wanted`). Therefore you know the angles between them are `wanted - current` and `360 - (wanted - current)`. Figuring out which of these is smaller is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

Just subtract the angles to get the relative angle you'd have to turn, i.e.

```py
turn = t.towards(0, 0) - t.heading()
```

The angles returned by `heading` and `towards` are always counted mathematically positive (counter-clockwise), so taking the difference like above is like measuring the angle span by starting from `heading` and then turning counter-clockwise until you reach the `towards` direction. In case this span crosses the 0° = 360° line, the resulting difference will be negative, since a value of 360° basically just gets lost to 0° on this line. Fix this by adding back the full circle of 360°. In a single formula, this can be done with modulo:

```py
turn = (t.towards(0, 0) - t.heading()) % 360
```

Now you have the positive angle it takes to turn counter-clockwise from `heading` to `towards`. Simply check if it's bigger than 180° to know if turning to the left is faster than to the right.

Comment: Ah thank you! It was passing the 0 = 360 mark that got me stuck. I'll give this a try later today.